# Generate data that can pass two-sample tests

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Is there any subfield of statistics that focuses on generating synthetic data that are hard to be distinguished from a given sample?

More formally, given $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\}$, suppose they are iid sampled from $p(x)$, but $p(x)$ is unknown to us. Can we devise a procedure to generate samples $\{x_1', x_2',\cdots, x_m'\}$ with arbitrary $m$, such that it is hard to distinguish them with two-sample tests? Is there any nontrivial solution that doesn't copy any $x_i$ to $x_j'$?

For example, one solution might be:

- Use point estimate to get a parameterized distribution such that ${x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n} \approx p_\theta(x)$
- Generate i.i.d. samples from $p_\theta(x)$.

However, is there any theoretical guarantee for this approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do for small samples from distributions that
are somewhat similar in shape and have the same means and standard deviations.
For example, here are ten observations (rounded to three places) from $\mathsf{Gamma}(shape = 3, rate = 1/2),$ hence with mean $\mu = 6, \sigma = \sqrt{12}.$

```
set.seed(1234);  x = round(rgamma(10, 3, 1/2), 3);  x
## 1.911 6.044 6.201 2.957 6.728 3.348 8.593 3.225 3.605 0.996
summary(x); sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.996   3.024   3.476   4.361   6.162   8.593 
## 2.401753
```

And here are are ten observations (rounded to three places) from
$\mathsf{Norm}(3, sqrt(12)).$

```
set.seed(4321);  y = round(rnorm(10, 6, sqrt(12)), 3); y
##  4.522  5.225  8.486  8.915  5.555 11.575  4.971  6.679 10.298  3.510
summary(y); sd(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 3.510   5.034   6.117   6.974   8.808  11.580 
## 2.696809
```

According to a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, the distributions from
which these samples were chosen cannot be distinguished by looking at the
samples.

```
ks.test(x, y)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x and y 
D = 0.5, p-value = 0.1678
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

In spite of the fact that the sample medians differ noticeably (3.476 vs. 6.117)
a nonparametric Wilcoxon rank sum test does not find a significant difference
between medians at the 5% level of significance.

```
wilcox.test(x, y)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x and y 
W = 24, p-value = 0.05243
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

This is harder to do with larger samples, but not impossible. Of course,
there is no guarantee that any two samples (even from the same distribution)
would not be found different by some test.

If I knew the purpose of generating such samples, I might be able to give
a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The purpose is to generate synthetic data (in high dimensional space) as if those data were from the distribution that gives $\{x_1, x_2,\cdots, x_n\}$. This might be similar to density estimation, but instead of knowing the probability densities we care more about sample quality. Also, a good density estimator might not correspond to a good sample generator.

Comment: OK, so you want to use the first sample as the basis for another possibly larger sample. And you want the second sample not to be detectably different from the first? That isn't exactly 'bootstrapping' but sounds something like it. Roughly, how big might the first and second samples be?

Comment: The first sample can be very large, such as 60000. The generated second samples can be as small as 1 or very large.

Comment: Then you might consider generating the second sample by sampling at random with replacement from the first.

Comment: Actually, this is what I considered to be a trivial solution (copying $x_i$ to $x_j'$) and hope to avoid.